# Why does make select pattern rule if only a substring matches?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, circular-dependency

I am writing a `makefile` that is supposed to create multiple executables from the code for different architectures. The idea is that the suffix of each executable indicates the architecture for which it was built. This is a simplified excerpt:

```
TARGET_NAME = foo
TARGET_AMD64 = $(TARGET_NAME)_amd64
TARGET_ARMHF = $(TARGET_NAME)_armhf
  
.PHONY:
all: $(TARGET_AMD64) $(TARGET_ARMHF) ;
    
$(TARGET_NAME)_%: lib/mylib.a
    @echo "$@ built."
   
lib/mylib.a: bin/mylib/src/mac/foo_ct.o
    @echo "$@ built."
```

When typing `make` I receive a circular dependency:

```
make: Circular bin/mylib/src/mac/foo_ct.o <- lib/mylib.a dependency dropped.
bin/mylib/src/mac/foo_ct.o built.
lib/mylib.a built.
foo_amd64 built.
foo_armhf built.
```

Apparently, `make` is looking for a rule that matches `bin/mylib/src/mac/foo_ct.o`. For reasons beyond my understanding, `make` takes `$(TARGET_NAME)_%` (the second rule).

Why is that the case? Only the filename `foo_ct.o` would match the pattern rule `$(TARGET_NAME)_%`, but why is the preceding path `bin/mylib/src/mac/` ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the [defined behaviour](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match):

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. After the comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule’s prerequisite patterns and the file name. The directories are ignored [...]

You will therefore have to specify your target with its absolute path:

```
TARGET_NAME = $(CURDIR)/foo
```

Note however, that `$(CURDIR)` is a GNU make extension.

---

Alternatively you could also specify a more specific rule for `bin/mylib/src/mac/foo_ct.o` to break the cycle:

```
TARGET_NAME = foo
TARGET_AMD64 = $(TARGET_NAME)_amd64
TARGET_ARMHF = $(TARGET_NAME)_armhf
  
.PHONY:
all: $(TARGET_AMD64) $(TARGET_ARMHF;
    
$(TARGET_NAME)_%: lib/mylib.a
    @echo "$@ built."
   
lib/mylib.a: bin/mylib/src/mac/foo_ct.o
    @echo "$@ built."

bin/mylib/src/mac/foo_ct.o:
    true
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that directory names in the file names are removed from the file before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. Now it makes sense.

Comment: Just FWIW, pattern rules themselves are a GNU make extension (to POSIX) so using `$(CURDIR)` doesn't cause the makefile to be any less portable.